# Filter specific values of optional argument with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:10, each = 6),
                      Site = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 6, times = 10),
                      Department = rep(c("E","F","G","H"), each = 6, times = 10),
                      Occupation = rep(c("I","J","K","L"), each = 6, times = 10),
                      Construct = rep(paste0("X",1:6), times = 10),
                      Score = sample(c("Green","Orange","Red"), size = 60, replace = TRUE))

head(df)
```

Basically, each ID belongs to a site, a department and has an occupation, and is evaluated on six constructs. 
I have adapted a previous function of mine to compute the N and the rate of each Score category for a given Construct, by any combination of Site, Department and Occupation :

```
my_function <- function(..., dimension = NULL){
      df %>%
      filter(Construct == dimension) %>%
      group_by(..., Score) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(rate= round(n/sum(n),2))
 }
```

This works perfectly, as I simply have to indicate which Construct, and add any of the three factors (Site, Departement, Occupation) as optional arguments to obtain a summary. For example, a summary of X1 by Site and Department would be :

```
my_function(dimension = "X1", Site, Department)
```

However, I would like to filter out some of the values of the Occupation variable, but only when looking at a summary including this variable. I tried to do so by checking whether Occupation was passed as an optional argument, and exclude the specific values when it was the case. Something like :

```
my_function <- function(..., dimension = NULL){
  if(hasArg(Occupation)){
    df %>%
      filter(Construct == dimension, Occupation != "I") %>%
      group_by(..., Score) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(rate= round(n/sum(n),2))
  } else {
    df %>%
      filter(Construct == dimension) %>%
      group_by(..., Score) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(rate= round(n/sum(n),2))
  }
}
```

But it does not seem to work, as it consistently returns includes the values I'd like to filter out, even when I specify Occupation as an optional argument. I tried to fiddle with things like curly-curly `{{}}` but I can't seem to get this function to filter the specific values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasArg` seems to expect all of the arguments to be *named*, whereas in

```r
my_function(dimension="X1", Site, Department, Occupation)
```

this is not the case.

Perhaps:

```r
my_function <- function(..., dimension = NULL){
  hasOcc <- "Occupation" %in% as.character(match.call())
  if (hasOcc) {
    df %>%
      filter(Construct == dimension, Occupation != "I") %>%
      group_by(..., Score) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(rate= round(n/sum(n),2))
  } else {
    df %>%
      filter(Construct == dimension) %>%
      group_by(..., Score) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(rate= round(n/sum(n),2))
  }
}
my_function(Site, Department, Occupation, dimension = "X1")
# # A tibble: 7 x 6
# # Groups:   Site, Department, Occupation [3]
#   Site  Department Occupation Score      n  rate
#   <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>  <int> <dbl>
# 1 B     F          J          Green      6   0.6
# 2 B     F          J          Orange     4   0.4
# 3 C     G          K          Green      2   0.2
# 4 C     G          K          Orange     2   0.2
# 5 C     G          K          Red        6   0.6
# 6 D     H          L          Green      6   0.6
# 7 D     H          L          Orange     4   0.4
```

Some other thoughts on the function:

- reaching out of its scope to get `df` is not a good practice: it is not really reproducible, and it can be difficult to troubleshoot. For instance, if you forget to assign your data to `df`, you'll see

  ```r
  my_function(Site, Department, Occupation, dimension = "X1")
  # Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  #   no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "function"
  ```

  (This error is because it is finding [`stats::df`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Fdist.html).)

  Further, if you want to use it against a different non-`df`-named dataset, you're out of luck.

  Recommendation: explicitly pass the data. A tidyverse commonality is to pass it as the first argument. One side-benefit of this is that you can (generally) use this in the middle of a `%>%`-pipe directly.

  ```r
  my_function <- function(.data, ..., dimension = NULL) { .data %>% ... }
  ```
- You can reduce the number of pipelines in there by including the `Occupation` conditional directly in the `filter(..)`. This is not just code-golf: in more complex code examples, it's not hard to imagine updating one of the `%>%`-pipes and either forgetting the other or updating it differently. Since the only difference here is a component of `filter`, we can add it there:

  ```r
  my_function <- function(..., dimension = NULL){
    hasOcc <- "Occupation" %in% as.character(match.call())
    df %>%
      filter(Construct == dimension, !hasOcc | Occupation != "I") %>%
      group_by(..., Score) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(rate= round(n/sum(n),2))
  }
  ```
- If `dimension` is required, don't default to `NULL` since, if omitted, this will produce an error.

  ```r
  my_function <- function(.data, ..., dimension) { ... }
  ```

  If it is instead optional and you don't want to filter on it if not provided, then you need to check for that in your `filter`:

  ```r
    filter(if (is.null(dimension)) TRUE else Construct == dimension, ...)
  ```
- If you can imagine wanting `dimension` to be either `NA` (matching an explicit `NA` value in the data) or you might want *"one or more"*, then you may want to use `%in%` instead of `==`:

  ```r
  NA == NA
  # [1] NA
  NA %in% NA
  # [1] TRUE
  ```

  So your function could use

  ```r
        filter(if (is.null(dimension)) TRUE else Construct %in% dimension, ...)
  ```

These points would result in your function being either

```r
my_function <- function(.data, ..., dimension = NULL){
  hasOcc <- "Occupation" %in% as.character(match.call())
  .data %>%
    filter(if (is.null(dimension)) TRUE else Construct %in% dimension, !hasOcc | Occupation != "I") %>%
    group_by(..., Score) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(rate= round(n/sum(n),2))
}
```

if `dimension` is optional, or

```r
my_function <- function(.data, ..., dimension) {
  hasOcc <- "Occupation" %in% as.character(match.call())
  .data %>%
    filter(Construct %in% dimension, !hasOcc | Occupation != "I") %>%
    group_by(..., Score) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(rate= round(n/sum(n),2))
}
```

otherwise.